# Deleting Files by Force!

Tags: filesystem, files, delete

Hi
I have a flash memory which is damaged and became read-only. I want to delete my data. How can I do so? Is there any way to make it completely impossible to read files on my flash memory?

Comment: Why not formatting it?

Comment: It became read-only I can't delete or format it. The files are not read-only,The whole thing is.

Answer (score 3):

Without destroying? You can repair it first. Assuming your flash is /dev/sdb1:

```
sudo fsck -a /dev/sdb1
```

If it succeeds, turn it on and off, then delete files.

Answer (score 2):

If the drive has become read-only on the *hardware* level because of an electronic problem or such, your only way is to destroy it, I suppose...

But some USB memory sticks can be made read-only with a switch, either a hardware switch (I guess you would know if it had one) or a software switch.  E.g. if it's an U3-compatible device, you might be able to do something with `u3-tool`.

Answer (score 0):

The original question, in part, was: "Is there any way to make it completely impossible to read files on my flash memory?"

To make the contents on the flash drive unreadable, use the '[shred](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/shred.1.html)' command.

Of course, before that command would work, `write` access to the flash drive would be necessary. In the event that `write` access cannot be enabled, the flash drive will need to be physically destroyed.